# How do I check if the current data set is "dirty"?

Tags: vue.js

How do I check if the current data set is dirty?

I want to do a quick check before posting the data. Given the following code snippet as an example:

```
save: function(e) {
    if(~~insert dirty check here~~) {
        $.ajax(e.currentTarget.action, {
            type: this.method,
            data: {
                _method: this.method,
                _token: this.token,
                data: JSON.stringify(this.card_data)
            }
        }).done($.proxy(function(content) {
            this.card_data = content;
            this.mode = 'view';
        }, this));
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you call dirty data ? Is this a vue.ps concept ?

Comment: The data has changed. I believe it to be part of the two way binding dictionary of terms, but I may be wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't seem like Vue.js uses any dirty checking.

> Vue.js is able to deliver the plain JavaScript object syntax without resorting to dirty checking by using Object.defineProperty, which is an ECMAScript 5 feature. It only works on DOM elements in IE8 and there's no way to polyfill it for JavaScript objects.

Source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/wiki/FAQ

> Vue.js has better performance because it doesn't use dirty checking.

Source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/96#issuecomment-35052704